# jQuery not working for button event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
var myVar;
        function colorChanger() {
                myVar = setInterval(function() { 
                var r,g,b,shadow,bottom,top;
                r = Math.floor((Math.random() * 253 ) + 1);
                g = Math.floor((Math.random() * 253 ) + 1);
                b = Math.floor((Math.random() * 253 ) + 1);
                shadow = Math.floor((Math.random() * 20 ) + 5);
                bottom = Math.floor((Math.random() * 80 ) + 1);
                    bbottom = Math.floor((Math.random() * 80 ) + 7);
                    ttop = Math.floor((Math.random() * 180 ) + 6);
                top = Math.floor((Math.random() * 200 ) + 9);
                size = (Math.random() * 100 ) + 10;
                   /* $("*").css("box-shadow",""+top+"px 0 "+shadow+"px rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+"), "+(-top)+"px 0 "+shadow+"px rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+"),0 "+(-bottom)+"px "+shadow+"px rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+"),0 "+(bottom)+"px "+shadow+"px rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")"); */
                    $("#startinterval").css("bottom","50%");
                    $("#startinterval").css("top",ttop+"px");
                document.getElementById("123").style.color = "rgba("+r+","+g+","+b+",0.3)";   
                document.getElementById("123").style.textShadow = top+"px "+(bottom)+"px "+shadow+"px rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+"), "+(-top)+"px "+bottom+"px "+shadow+"px rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+"),"+top+"px "+(-bottom)+"px "+shadow+"px rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+"),"+(-top)+"px "+(-bottom)+"px "+shadow+"px rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")";
                    document.getElementById("123").style.textShadow = top+"px 0 "+shadow+"px rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+"), "+(-top)+"px 0 "+shadow+"px rgb("+r+","+g+","+g+"),0 "+(-bottom)+"px "+shadow+"px rgb("+b+","+g+","+b+"),0 "+(bottom)+"px "+shadow+"px rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")",top+"px "+(bottom)+"px "+shadow+"px rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+"), "+(-top)+"px "+bottom+"px "+shadow+"px rgb("+g+","+r+","+b+"),"+top+"px "+(-bottom)+"px "+shadow+"px rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+"),"+(-top)+"px "+(-bottom)+"px "+shadow+"px rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")";
                document.getElementById("13").style.backgroundColor = "rgba("+b+","+r+","+g+",0.2)";
                document.getElementById("13").style.bottom = bottom+"%";
                document.getElementById("13").style.top = top+"%";
                document.getElementById("choosen").innerHTML = "rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")";
                $("button").click(function() {
                    $("button").css({"border-radius":bottom+"px"});
                });
            }, 20);
        }
```

**HTML code :**

```
    <div align="center">
      <h2 style="font-weight: 900;font-size: 40px, -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;"><p id="123">Random Text</p></h2>
<button class="btn btn-info" onclick="colorChanger()" id="startinterval">start Animation</button>
<button onclick="stopColor()">stop Animation</button> 
      </div>
```

I recently started with jQuery and I'm really sorry if this is a lame question. In above code On Clicking the button it's supposed to change the radius of the button to "variable" value but it's not working.I tried using className, element-id but no luck. Any help will be appreciated. Thankyou.

Comment: whats the value of variable?

Comment: [Works fine for me](https://jsfiddle.net/1t8acskd/) so you're clearly doing something else wrong...

Comment: I posted the full script can you please go through @Zain Farroq

Comment: After seeing your function i think you are calling this function on click of any item. And you want to trigger the click event in that function. so by this way that action will not trigger you should trigger the click event to apply the radius on the button.

Comment: You should probably separate the button click event from the `colorChange` function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For trigger click event on button you have to add below line

```
    $("button").trigger( "click" );
    $("button").click(function() {
                    $("button").css({"border-radius":bottom+"px"});
                });
```

This will trigger the click event on button.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just add another declaration to that function ...

```
document.getElementById("[the buttons id]").style.borderRadius = '8px';
```

No real need to throw jQuery into a non-jQuery function. (not that it's a problem, just unnecessary).

Answer (score -1):

your code have syntax error. border-radius and pixels should be seperated by ','

`correct syntax: $("button").css("border-radius",variable+"px");`

Comment: `.css({"property":"value"})` is perfectly valid.